# Enter text into web form with C# program?

Tags: c#, facebook, forms

Hey there I need to enter in some text into web text fields using a C# program.

Basically for my own personal use I've developed a desktop facebook chat application (which I may release as freeware since everyone hates the web chat).

This application works great but I need to somehow take log a person in via the program, this is the bit that stifles me, anyone have any solutions?

my current idea is to have a form for the username and password which then puts the information in a webBrowser control within the program in the appropriate fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to create a POST request to the server to log the user in.**

To do this you need to use the `System.Net.WebRequest` class, [this excellent article describes how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx#Y40).

To figure how exactly how to construct the request, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture it when you log into your own account.  Using this you can construct an identical request using `WebRequest` - except substitute the username / password where necessary.

This is the only real way you can achieve this.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try it and let you know of the outcome

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest logging in with a POST request as well, but since you are already using a webBrowser control (correct?) then you can use code such as this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("email")[0].SetAttribute("Value", textBox1.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("pass")[0].SetAttribute("Value", textBox2.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[0].InvokeMember("submit");
```

That will login to facebook just fine.

Also consider looking at XMPP libs, such as http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

Facebook chat supports the XMPP protocol so you can get rid of a lot of the hard work and just worry
about making the front-end look nice for the user.

To login to XMPP via facebook its your facebook_username@chat.facebook.com and your facebook password.